# Design Pattern: OOPs and Inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have one Parent class and two Child Classes.
Also it has getEmployeeDetails which returns Type Employee. Employee is an abstract class extended by Manager and Engineer.

Sample Code:

```
public class Parent{

    public Employee getEmployeeDetails(int id){
        //doStuff
    }
}

public class child1 extends Parent{
    @Override
    public Manager getEmployeeDetails(int id){
        //doStuff
    }
}

public class child2 extends Parent{
}
```

Now I want my child1 to override getEmployeeDetails and return type manager. Also if I want to set employee specific details in Parent and override this and add on more to oveerridden method, what should be done in parent as Employee is abstract class? Also, please suggest any better pattern.

Comment: use `super.setEmployeeDetails(int id)` to set employee specific details and add on more to oveerridden method

Comment: @Codegeek Looks like there is no need for `Parent` to be  a `class`. It can be a n `interface`

Comment: @Darshan Patel it needs more to be added

Comment: @Cking I have some common stuff for engineer and manager. Hence Interface cannot be the solution.

Comment: Ideally getEmployeeDetails & setEmployeeDetails method's definition should be in Employee class rather than in Parent. get&set methods should be called in Child1 & Child2 class via Manager & Engineer objects or whatever your requirement is in class child2. Override the get & setEmployeeDetail methods in Manager & Engineer class. I don't see any need for calling getEmployeeDetails method in parent class.

Comment: I know it should be in employee... I am just giving one scenario where I am stuck up. The above example is not realtime one. I have similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Parent{

    public final Employee getEmployeeDetails(int id){
        //doStuff
        return getEmployeeDetailsImpl(id);
    }

    protected abstract Employee getEmployeeDetailsImpl(int id);
}

public final class child1 extends Parent{
    @Override
    protected final Employee getEmployeeDetails(int id){
        //doStuff
        return new Manager(id);
    }
}

public final class child2 extends Parent{
    @Override
    protected final Employee getEmployeeDetails(int id){
        //doStuff
        return new Engineer(id);
    }
}
```

You may need to adapt the signature of `getEmployeeDetailsImpl` according to your needs.